# Imputation of missing values

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I would like to impute missing values in a data set based on the distribution of the other values of the variable.

Imagine that 30 % of the values = 1, 20 % = 2 and 50 % = 3, in effect I'd like to do the following :

```
impute(var,1) # for 30 % of the NA occurrences #
impute(var,2) # for 20 % of the NA occurrences #
impute(var,3) # for 50 % of the NA occurrences #
```

Can anybody help ?

John

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want:

```
var[is.na(var)] <- sample(1:3, sum(is.na(var)), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3,0.2,0.5))
```

Comment: This returns the values 2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2 and the following warning :  In var[is.na(var)] <- sample(1:3, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Thanks James, this still doesn't seem to work correctly. Running the code 5 times I get 20 x 1, 9 x 2 and 21 x 3 which corresponds to the probabilities p(1)=0.4, p(2)=0.18 and p(3)=0.42. Maybe running enough repetitions, the probabilities will converge towards the desired levels.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to impute missing values in a data set based on the distribution of the other values of the variable.

I am very happy with the **pamr** package by Tibshirany. It bases the imputation on the k nearest neighbours of the missing data points. Simply calling:

```
imputed.matrix  <- pamr.knnimpute(list(x==matrix.with.missing.data))[['x']]
```

usually works fine.

Note that `pamr.knnimpute` is non-deterministic; typical correlation over all imputed pairs is > 0.9 though.